# MS word: footnotes references are not recognized and set as normal style (from google doc to word)

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, google-drive

When I download a google doc as .docx and opened it in MS word, the footnote references (little numbers) are not recognized as "footnote style" but as "normal style" (even if they behave like normal footnote)

It's a problem because to change the references style in MS word (eg. the size of the little number assign to each ref.) we must select each reference number to apply the reference style on them. (We can't update all the footnote references by updating the "footnote style" because the reference numbers don't have that style).

So if I change the footnote style and update it, the new style will be applies normally to the new footnote (recognized as such) but won't apply to the old footnote created in google doc since they are in normal style.

The question is strange: **how to force word to apply the footnote style to all the footnote references?**[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really an answer, but more a dirty workaround: select all the superscript and apply the style. I did not find the right regex but MS word did.

[image]